# Get substring from string

Tags: iphone, string

I get date and time from server in the format **Thu, 16 Feb 2012 13:54:41 +0000**

Here I want just  **Thu, 16 Feb 2012** string from whole string .
Can anyone tell me hoe i can take out this string.

Answer (score 1):

In order of personal preference . . .

a) I'd parse it (using [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) into an `NSDate` object. They you can do whatever you want with it.

b) If you really only want the first part of the string, look into [regular expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

c) If you're *very* confident about the formatting of the string, you could split it by the ' ' character and then join the first 3 substrings together :

```
NSArray *sub = [myDateString componentsSeperatedByString:@" "];
NSString *newDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", 
                           [sub objectAtIndex:0],
                           [sub objectAtIndex:1],
                           [sub objectAtIndex:2]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example

```
        NSString *dateStr = @"Thu, 16 Feb 2012 13:54:41 +0000";
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         //NSDate *today = [NSDate date]
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
        //NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy"];
        NSString *newStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
        NSLog(@"date: %@", newStr);
        [dateFormat release];
```